How to use "Previous Tag" as a feature?
I was implementing a CRF based POS tagging model using CRFsuite. I have included the features like checking if the word is capitalized, prefix of the word, suffix of the word, etc. However, these features are word based features.
I want to include POS tags based features in my prediction model.
If I simply define the POS tag feature as follows
features = {
    ...
    'prevpos' : '' if i==0 else sentence[i-1][1],
    ...
}

I have no doubt that this will work for training my model on the corpus. But, when I will use it to predict POS tags for my test sentence, I am unsure about the behavior of this model. Because I think that the feature to extract the previous tag should not work as we do not know them previously.
Also, I do not know the behavior shown by the line X_test_sentence = sent2features(test_sentence_tagged) which will extract the features of the test sentence. And when I use my training model for predicting, tags = crf.predict_single(X_test_sentence) I have no idea about how the previous tags (say we assign dummy tags to test sentence words) will affect (or will not affect) the prediction.
